# how to use bootstrap to create boxes image attached

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[How to create boxes like in the image attached using bootstrap, boxes next to each other without a padding or margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0qh8.jpg)

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to define a css class for it:

```css
.no-padding{
padding:0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">5</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding">6</div>
</div>
```